# Limit of product of cosines: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \cos(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{4})\cos(\frac{x}{6})\cdots\cos(\frac{x}{2^n})$

Tags: calculus, limits

We've got this problem $$ y= \lim_{n \to \infty} \cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\cdots\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)$$ 
I have got stuck in this problem of evaluating the limits. What I was thinking was to convert $$\cos\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)$$ somehow to $\sin$ and thus term might fully get dissolved for a shorter expression and we can evaluate value of limit.

Comment: Let $y_n$ be the $n$-th partial product. What is $y_n\cdot \sin\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)$?

Comment: As you can see, MathJax also works in titles -- and we make good use of it. Also, if you use `\cos` in place of `cos`, it'll be typeset in a nicer font: $\cos$ vs. $cos$.